# [php]How to convert array values to one array value with comma?

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to connect the key genres, country, in one value
eg [genres] => value1, value2, value3
because there is a problem such that the Values from previous loop are added to the next loop

Here is printscreen http://s12.postimg.org/sv53nakej/Bez_tytu_u.png

```
  1./////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
           stdClass Object
            (
                [title] => Marsjanin
                [origTitle] => The Martian
                [genres] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [key] => 28
                                [value] => akcja
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [key] => 33
                                [value] => sci-fi
                            )

                    )

                [country] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [key] => 53
                                [value] => USA
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [key] => 53
                                [value] => Australia
                            )
                    )

            )

    2./////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            stdClass Object
            (
                [title] => Pięćdziesiąt twarzy Greya
                [origTitle] => Fifty Shades of Grey
                [genres] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [key] => 16
                                [value] => melodramat
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [key] => 33
                                [value] => sci-fi
                            )
                    )

                [country] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [key] => 53
                                [value] => USA
                            )


                    )


            )
```

This is my code:

```
foreach( $urll as $urle){

$results = My_Parser::getMovie($urle);

        foreach($results as $itemz => $valuez) {
        if($itemz=='genres'){
        foreach($valuez as $val) {
            $genr[] = $val['value'];
        }}
        }

        $genre = implode(', ', $genr);

        echo '<tr><th>'.$genre.'</th><th>Importuj</th></tr>'; 

}
```

Values from previous loop are added to the next

ex.

1. A
2. B
3. C
4. D

Result:

A = A

**A**+B = B

**A**+**B**+C = C

**A**+**B**+**C**+D = D

Output [genres]

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => akcja
        [1] => sci-fi
    )

    Array
    (
        [0] => akcja   / Incorect value added from first array
        [1] => sci-fi  /  Incorect value added from first array
        [2] => melodramat    
        [3] => sci-fi
    )
```

Comment: expand! Your question is vague. I will update my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$genr` is being appended to constantly. Reset it before entering the nested loop:

```
foreach( $urll as $urle){
    ...
    $genr = array(); // Add this!
    foreach($results as $itemz => $valuez) {
       ...
    }
    ...
    $genre = implode(', ', $genr); // Now you're good.
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the array before the foreach of `foreach($valuez as $val)`

```
 foreach( $urll as $urle){

    $results = My_Parser::getMovie($urle);

        foreach($results as $itemz => $valuez) {
            if($itemz=='genres'){
             $genr=array();  //initialization
            foreach($valuez as $val) {
                $genr[] = $val['value'];
                }
               $genre = implode(', ', $genr); // use the variable -- As per as your requirement.
               echo '<tr><th>'.$genre.'</th><th>Importuj</th></tr>'; 
             }

            }

    }
```